# How to develop GWT code(Java) and Appengine code(Python) in one single Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

The one that close to my question is shown below but I don't understand at all.

[integration-of-gwt-into-appengine](http://blog.loxal.net/2008/08/integration-of-gwt-into-appengine.html)

Could anyone give me more details ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Eclipse project, you can have as many "projects inside" as you have folders. You just need to structure your overall "top level project" in a folder-modular fashion.

- top level folder

  - gui project folder
  - server project folder

When you get to "create a project" (whether Java or anything else), you change the "default folder" to a sub-folder inside your top level project.